# How to combine text that has spilled over multiple rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I scraped a PDF in R using tabulizer and saw that multi-line text often spilled over into multiple rows, like so:

```
              item quantity price
1   PURCHASE ORDER       NA    NA
2    ITEM CODE ABC       NA    NA
3  1 Computer soft        3 10.99
4             ware       NA    NA
5         2 Mathem        2  8.50
6 atics curriculum       NA    NA
7  and calculators       NA    NA
```

I would like to combine the text across multiple rows into a limited number of rows, so it looks like this:

```
  item                                    quantity price
1 PURCHASE ORDER ITEM CODE ABC                NA    NA  
2 1 Computer software                           3 10.99
3 2 Mathematics curriculum and calculators      2  8.5
```

Here is the code for recreating these tibbles:

```
#Messy tibble
item <- c("PURCHASE ORDER", "ITEM CODE ABC", "1 Computer soft", "ware", "2 Mathem", "atics curriculum", "and calculators")
quantity <- c(NA, NA, 3, NA, 2, NA, NA)
price <- c(NA, NA, 10.99, NA, 8.50, NA, NA)
df <- data.frame(item, quantity, price)
df

#Clean tibble
item <- c("PURCHASE ORDER ITEM CODE ABC", "1 Computer software", "2 Mathematics curriculum and calculators")
quantity <- c(NA, 3, 2)
price <- c(NA, 10.99, 8.50)
df <- data.frame(item, quantity, price)
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could identify the groups by those that have missing values on `quantity` and `price`.  Then, make unique group identifiers for the text that will go together.  Finally, you can paste the text together and take the values of `quantity` and `price` that belong to the first observation in each group:

```r
library(dplyr)
item <- c("PURCHASE ORDER", "ITEM CODE ABC", "1 Computer soft", "ware", "2 Mathem", "atics curriculum", "and calculators")
quantity <- c(NA, NA, 3, NA, 2, NA, NA)
price <- c(NA, NA, 10.99, NA, 8.50, NA, NA)
df <- data.frame(item, quantity, price)
df
#>               item quantity price
#> 1   PURCHASE ORDER       NA    NA
#> 2    ITEM CODE ABC       NA    NA
#> 3  1 Computer soft        3 10.99
#> 4             ware       NA    NA
#> 5         2 Mathem        2  8.50
#> 6 atics curriculum       NA    NA
#> 7  and calculators       NA    NA

df %>% 
  mutate(grp = ifelse(is.na(quantity) & is.na(price) & !row_number() == 1, 0, 1),
         grp = cumsum(grp)) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  reframe(item = paste(item, collapse=" "), 
            across(c(quantity, price), first)) %>%
  select(-grp)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   item                                      quantity price
#>   <chr>                                        <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 PURCHASE ORDER ITEM CODE ABC                    NA  NA  
#> 2 1 Computer soft ware                             3  11.0
#> 3 2 Mathem atics curriculum and calculators        2   8.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you. Only thing is I got an error saying "could not find function "reframe"" so I used summarise() instead.

Comment: You're welcome.  The `reframe()` function is in `dplyr` (I'm using version 1.1.2).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option to tidy up your data:

Note: IMHO the first two rows (`"PURCHASE ...."`) reflect the column name and should be dropped.

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df |> 
  mutate(no = as.numeric(str_extract(item, "^\\d+"))) |> 
  fill(no) |> 
  replace_na(list(no = 0)) |> 
  group_by(no) |> 
  summarise(across(everything(), \(x) paste0(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = " "))) |> 
  select(-no)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   item                                      quantity price  
#>   <chr>                                     <chr>    <chr>  
#> 1 PURCHASE ORDER ITEM CODE ABC              ""       ""     
#> 2 1 Computer soft ware                      "3"      "10.99"
#> 3 2 Mathem atics curriculum and calculators "2"      "8.5"
```

Answer (score 1):

From your post, it is not clear if `quantity` or `price` will have a value for the same line item. So, I simply took the `sum`, you can decide how to aggregate these lines.

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(line = cumsum(grepl("^\\d+", item))) |>
  summarize(item = paste(item, collapse = " "),
            across(c(quantity, price), ~if(any(!is.na(.x))) sum(.x, na.rm = T) else NA),
            .by = line) |>
  select(-line)
```

The first "line" does not have any values nor does it start with a digit like the others. As mentioned by @stefan if these are some type of header that you want to exclude, you can simplify the across statement to `across(c(quantity, price), na.omit)` and change `summarize` to `reframe`.

**Output**

```
                                       item quantity price
1              PURCHASE ORDER ITEM CODE ABC       NA    NA
2                      1 Computer soft ware        3 10.99
3 2 Mathem atics curriculum and calculators        2  8.50
```